# How to add a filter using regex NOT IN?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I am currently looking to extract data from Google Analytics using a python script. I need to include a filter condition in my script to exclude a set of network domains to the existing list of filters applied.

The network domain values that I want to exclude are:

1. (not set)
2. unknown.unknown
3. trackapp.net

Below is the filter as it currently exists:

```
'filter':'ga:medium==orgainc;ga:source==campaign;ga:landingPagePath=~(1234|5678)
```

How can I add another filter condition here using regex to exclude the 3 network domains mentioned above.

Comment: GA UI will allow only to query and extract the data into a CSV file. I'm looking to query for many days at once, hence creating this script and saving the data in JSON. Not well versed with regex functions and how to use it in a Python script, hence the question here.

Comment: Okay, I see. But do you want to extend your GA filters or create/extend a Python script that does the extra filtering?

Comment: The filter I've shared is already being used in my Python script. I want to extend that  by using the ga:networkDomain dimension and exclude the 3 domains. So yes, I would like to extend my current filter. It should be something like:

'filter':'ga:medium==orgainc;ga:source==campaign;ga:landingPagePath=~(1234|5678);ga:networkDomain<insert_regex_here>

Answer (score 0):

Extend your query like this:

```
ga:networkDomain!~(^$|unknown\.unknown|trackapp\.net)
```

However, the `^$` not-set/empty-string part using the start/end position operators may not work as expected on your ga:networkDomain field.